# Measuring unit of Spatial Coherence

Tags: optics, coherence

Usually, the temporal coherence of light is described with the coherence length. This quantity can be measured conveniently with an interferometer and is directly related to the coherence time and the spectral bandwidth. It is often stated in the data sheets of lasers.

Is there a similar measuring unit for the spatial coherence? As far as I know, the most simple setup for measuring the spatial coherence is the double slit experiment of Young. However, I am having trouble to find a *measuring unit that tells to what degree a beam of light is spatial coherent*. In most explanations, the spatial coherence is described qualitative. But how to obtain a quantitative value for it, is often omitted.

Comment: Either a length or area depending on context or taste.  The region on a plane where radiation from two sources is coherent.  Add temporal/length coherence, and you can consider a coherence volume, meters cubed.

Comment: @garyp That sounds reasonable. Is there any link for more details about this? A Google search regarding "spatial coherence plane" was not very fruitful. It makes intuitively sense, but it does not seem to be the most often used measuring unit for the spatial coherence if Google gives not much information regarding this

Comment: Try *coherence area*.  It might be more common to use *coherence length* with the understanding that the length in question is perpendicular to the propagation direction.  This is to be confused :-) with the other meaning of *coherence length* where it is understood that the length is in the same direction as the direction of propagation.

Comment: @garyp Thank you, for "spatial coherence area", there are a lot of good results